# Find a list of values less than a particular value from a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list:

```
var hardcodedList = new List<int> { 1000, 2000, 5000, 7000, 10000 };
```

and I want to find out the values, less than the value passed as input, from that list.

I was trying to write something like this:

```
var newList = hardcodedList.Where(x => x.Value <= passedValue).ToList;
```

But this doesn't work because Value property is not available. Please help me in finding the solution.

Comment: `x` is the `int` e.g  `hardcodedList.Where(x => x <= passedValue)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `value` over `x`.`x` represents each item of `hardcodedList`.  use the following code :

```
        var inputNumber = 3000;
        var hardcodedList = new List<int> { 1000, 2000, 5000, 7000, 10000 };
        var result = hardcodedList.Where(x => x <= inputNumber).ToList();
```

The above code returns just `1000`,`2000` as a result.

Comment: Why I have got `-1` for? what's wrong with this code?

Comment: As far as I can see there is nothing wrong. This answer is fine.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias but  it got `down vote` first

Comment: Osman maybe they thought that the answer was too trivial. But in any case it doesn't really matter. You shouldn't be concerned too much about a single downvote, it can happen for any kind of random reasons.

Comment: @osmanRahimi Thanks for the answer, I have accepted it. I don't know why there was downvote for your answer. I got 4 downvotes for the question, I know that it might be a very easy question for some people but didn't understand the reason for downvotes because there are beginners also who use this portal.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newList = hardcodedList.Where(x => x.Value <= passedValue).ToList();
```

This won't compile.

hardCodedList is a sequence of integers. Every element of the sequence is one integer.

The parameter in your `Where` is a `Func<TSource, bool>`. In normal language: the parameter is a function with one input parameter of type TSource, and a return value of bool.

The type of TSource is the same type as the type of the elements in your sequence. In your case: TSource is an int. So the parameter in your Where should be a function that has as input one int, an element of your input sequence, and as output a bool, which says whether you want to keep the element (true), or not (false).

```
x => x.Value <= passedValue
```

As your input sequence is a sequence of integers, the `x` here represents one integer. You create a function like:

```
bool ShouldIKeepThisElement(int x)
{
    return x.Value <= passedValue;
}
```

It is easy to see why this does not compile.

If you want to keep all integers from your list that have a value smaller or equal to passedValue, you would have created a method like:

```
bool ShouldIKeepThisElement(int x)
{
    return x <= passedValue;
}
```

Or as a lambda expression:

```
Func<int, bool> predicate = x => x <= passedValue;
```

This will compile, and you can put it in your `Where`:

```
int passedValue = ...;
IEnumerable<int> smallIntegers = hardCodedList.Where(x => x < passedValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, it was useful.